# SUM in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you help me to make the sum of all the values ​​of the "Total_Profit" row that is in partition 1 of my database.

```
select 
    Total_Profit, 
    $partition.FUNCIONDEPARTICION2(Order_Priority) 
from 
    cliente 
where 
    $partition.FUNCIONDEPARTICION2(Order_Priority) = 1
```

In this query I already show all the values ​​but I don't know how to add them

Comment: add your sample and expected data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `SUM()`:

```
select SUM(Total_Profit)
from cliente 
where $partition.FUNCIONDEPARTICION2(Order_Priority) = 1
```